# php mysql - get more than 1 record in single query

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table like

```
<table width="60%" border="0">
    <tr>
        <td>intId</td>
        <td>tagname</td>
        <td>cid</td>
        <td>lid</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>chemis</td>
        <td>5</td>
        <td>0</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>hist</td>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>0</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>canada</td>
        <td>0</td>
        <td>9</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>chemis</td>
        <td>6</td>
        <td>0</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>5</td>
        <td>chemis</td>
        <td>9</td>
        <td>2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>6</td>
        <td>hist</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>1</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

```
$srarchkey_arr = array('chemis','tes','loyal','hist','canada');
```

My output should be

```
<table width="60%" border="0">
    <tr>
        <td>Tag Name </td>
        <td>cid</td>
        <td>lid</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Chemis</td>
        <td>5,6,9</td>
        <td>0,0,2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>hist</td>
        <td>4,3,</td>
        <td>0,1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>canada</td>
        <td>0</td>
        <td>9</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

[Please refer the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/L7ZHF/1/)

i.e In my tags table i have lots of tags with cid and lid

I want to search the words which are in array `$srarchkey_arr`. I want to search these tags and give the output as specified. I used the like query but it gives the out put as individual record. So i again use loops to concat the cid and lids.

Is this possible to do this with single query and loop. Is there any possibility to pass this like array or like `in()` for strings.

Please help me. thanks

Comment: It would be great if you could provide the part of your php code where you execute and handle the query, it is hard to help without knowing how you are doing this.

Comment: use group_concat function

Answer (score 1):

use this sql

```
SELECT tagname, group_concat(cid), group_concat(lid) from test.check group by tagname;
```